# PHP string replace exclude string inside braces

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = "PHP is a server-side {{scripting language}} designed for {{web development}} but also used as a general-purpose programming language";
$search = 'language';
$replace = 'english';

$new_str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```

In the above code, how can we exclude the string inside {{ ... }}. such that the output should be

```
"PHP is a server-side {{scripting language}} designed for {{web development}} but also used as a general-purpose programming english"
```

Comment: How is your string different than the output you showed afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead of [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$pattern = sprintf('/{{[^}]+}}(*SKIP)(*F)|%s/', preg_quote($search, '/'));
$new_str = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```

`{{[^}]+}}` matches the contents inside `{{...}}` block, `(*SKIP)(*F)` skips it, and `%s` (which is substituted with the escaped search string) matches the required word.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/179086)